# HTTP proxy in OpenBSD 5.8 (replacing Apache ProxyPass)

Tags: openbsd, reverse-proxy, openbsd-httpd

I'm trying to replace Apache with OpenBSDs httpd but can't figure out what to do with my ProxyPass statements.

In apaches conf it looks like this

```
 ProxyPass /someurl http://192.168.123.123/someotherurl
 ProxyPassReverse /someurl http://192.168.123.123/someotherurl
```

- I thought I should use relayd for this, but how do I do the URL rewrite?
- Would I set up relayd to listen on port 80 and forward some things to different internal machines and the rest to httpd on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Great question!  OpenBSD's newly written [`httpd`](http://bxr.su/o/usr.sbin/httpd/) is not a fully-featured web-server, and [nor is it intended to be](http://cvsweb.allbsd.org/cvsweb.cgi/src/usr.sbin/httpd/httpd.c?cvsroot=openbsd#rev1.1).  As for [`relayd`](http://bxr.su/o/usr.sbin/relayd/), which was the precursor to `httpd`, I do not believe that it has any ability to do what you require, either.

The best general-purpose replacement for [Apache](http://ports.su/www/apache-httpd) bar none is still [nginx](http://ports.su/www/nginx).

It is readily available in the [OpenBSD ports tree as `www/nginx`](http://openbsd.su/ports/www/nginx), and can be easily installed as a precompiled package with [`pkg_add(1)`](http://mdoc.su/o/pkg_add.1) — `doas pkg_add nginx`.

Once you install nginx, you would use the [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) directive, and it'll probably look like this:

```
location /someurl {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.123.123/someotherurl; 
}
```

As for `ProxyPassReverse`, nginx has a more appropriate name for it — [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect), and the default value of `default` should already be sufficient for your needs (that is, if your `ProxyPassReverse` and `ProxyPass` directives both had the same value).  Good luck!